# Checkbox live filtering from mysql in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

I have problem with checkbox filtering.
I have main page where user can search database by:
- city
- time
-category

On the RESULT page, link looks like this:

```
restaurants?city=1&datepick=&category=3
```

So, my Restaurants controller looks like this:

```
function index()
    {

    $city= $this->input->get('city') ? $this->input->get('city') : '';
    $datepick= $this->input->get('datepick') ? $this->input->get('datepick') : '';
    $category = $this->input->get('category') ? $this->input->get('category') : '';



    $form_data = array(
            'city' => $city,
            'datepick' => $datepick,
            'category' => $category

        );

    $this->load->model('rest_search');

    $res = $this->rest_search->rest_main_search($form_data);

    if(!empty($res)){
        $data['result'] = $res['restaurant_details'];
        $this->load->view('Search', $data); 


    } else {

        $this->load->view('Error_102'); 

    }
```

Model rest_search:

```
function rest_main_search($form_data) { 


    $city= $form_data['city'];
    $datepick= $form_data['datepick'];
    $category= $form_data['category']; 

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('restaurants');



    if (!empty($city) && !empty($category)) {
        $this->db->where(array(
            'city'=>$city,
            'category'=>$category
            ));
    } else if(!empty($city) && empty($category)) {
        $this->db->where(array(
            'city'=>$city
            ));
    } else if(empty($city) && !empty($category)) {
        $this->db->where(array(
            'category'=>$category
            ));
    }
    $query = $this->db->get()->result();
}
```

View file (short version):

```
<?php 
if(!empty($result)) {
foreach($result as $line) {

?>

<div class="rest_holder main_window">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <?php echo $line->img; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <?php echo $line->name; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>  
<?php } } ?>
```

This is OK, and it works as it should:

Now, I have some extra filters (sort by...) with checkboxes as well as checkboxes for city and category.
I know I can achieve this with AJAX but I'm little bit confused how to combine it with my regular (_GET) search.

Any idea?

Comment: Can you attach your html here, you can send checkboxes data with method="GET" in your form without problem, and you will accept that data with $this->input->get() like you are doing now.

Comment: Thanks for answering... I need live filtering without refreshing the page. I guess I should use AJAX. I tried to hide (display:none) existing result and display new result but I'm sure it' bad solution.

Comment: Yes ajax would be great, on ajax request you need to return data from rest_main_search method, and in ajax success method to manipulate DOM as you want, no show hiding, just block UI before ajax request, and unblock on ajax complete. And while waiting for data display some loader image...

Comment: OK, I've updated post with VIEW file (short version).